# NHibernate Session.save and transaction.Commit

Tags: database, nhibernate, transactions

I have a problem here in my workflow will be glad if you all could help

```
using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
 {
   try          
   {
      obj1 = Session.Save(obj1);
      obj2=Session.Save(obj2);
      transaction.Commit();
    }               
   catch
    {
      transaction.Rollback();
    }
  }
```

Now the  scenario is that obj1 gets saved but obj2 gives an error and transaction is rolled back.

Now when i start a new operation in which both the obj1 and obj2 get saved and when the transaction commits it saves obj1,obj2 and the previous obj1 also.
Please help me handle this.
   I dont want to save the previous obj1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close and dispose of a session if it throws exception or you have to rollback. It probably saves obj1, because once session throws exception, the session is in inconsistent state.

Create new session and transaction.

[Documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-endingsession-commit)

> currentTransaction.Rollback();
>
> If you rollback the transaction you should immediately close and discard the current session to ensure that NHibernate's internal state is consistent.

[9.8. Exception handling](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-endingsession-commit#manipulatingdata-exceptions)

> If the ISession throws an exception you should immediately rollback the transaction, call ISession.Close() and discard the ISession instance. Certain methods of ISession will not leave the session in a consistent state.